# Find element in array using recursion - javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion

I'm trying to select Nth element from array using this function:

```
function nthArr(arr, index){
    if (index === 0)
        return arr[index];
    else nthArr(arr.slice(1), --index);
}

nthArr([1,2,3,4,5,6],3)
```

I would await that it returns `4`, but instead I get 'undefined'.
How should I return correct value?

Comment: Shouldn't there be a `return` somewhere after `else`?

Comment: Ummm... but why? Doesn't `arr[index]` work for all indices anyway?

Comment: @JohnBupit arrays[] are accessed by index

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing a `return` statement in the `else` branch.

```
if (index === 0)
    return arr[index];
else {
    return nthArr(arr.slice(1), --index); // Note the return
}
```

Comment: exactly - my java habits :-)

Answer (score 2):

You're missing a `return` statement...But why not just simplify the whole thing?

```js
function nthArr(arr, index){
  return arr[index];
}

var result = document.getElementById('result');
result.textContent = nthArr([1,2,3,4,5,6], 3);
```

```html
<span id="result"></span>
```

Comment: yes this is simpler, but I needed it for traversing list object